# Java implement interface method using subtype

Tags: java, oop

Im attempting to implement a custom Java interface, using an object subtype.

**Therefore, we have an interface:**

```
public interface Information_Object {

    public Data_Object getDataObject(String string);

    public void putDataObject(String string, Data_Object d);

}
```

**The snippet of the implementation class:**

```
public class HashmapBackedInformationObject implements Information_Object {
    
    private static DigitalObjectRegistry newDigitalObjectRegistry = new DigitalObjectRegistry(); 

    public DigitalObject getDataObject(String DOID) {
        
        return newDigitalObjectRegistry.getDataObjectMap().get(DOID);
    }
  
    public void putDataObject(String DOID, DigitalObject dataObject) {
       
       
        newDigitalObjectRegistry.getDataObjectMap().put(DOID, dataObject); 
        
    }
}
```

The problem is the compiler reports that `getDataObject(String DOID)` & `putDataObject(String string, Data_Object d)` are not implemented.

DigitalObject is a child/subtype of Data_Object.

[image: Add]

How can provide an implementation for the interface using a child type?

Thanks

Comment: Your implementation _must_ match the interface, method for method.  No changes in signature.  You are free to return a `DigitalObject` from `getDataObject`, however the method signature must be written `public Data_Object getDataObject() { return someDigitalObject; } `  One more tip, if you annotate your methods with @Override, then you will know beforehand that you have a problem.  EG., `@Override public Data_Object getDataObject() {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The `getDataObject` method should work; not sure why you get an error there. Are you sure you're reporting the error correctly?

However, `putDataObject` is simply wrong. The contract of `Information_Object` specifies that any implementation of the interface can take **any** `Data_Object` as an argument. However, the implementation in `HashmapBackedInformationObject` specifies that it only accepts `DigialObject`s. That's a failure to implement the interface correctly.

In computer science terms, method arguments are not *covariant*, but you're trying to make them so.

Comment: so one solution is the extend `Information_Object` interface into `Digital_Information_Object` interface were methods have the type `DigialObject` rather than `DataObject`. What do you think?

Comment: Using generics, and parametrize your interface, is an other solution

Comment: No, and no. Extending the interface does nothing, since the base interface's contract must still be fulfilled. Your interface is simply impossible to fulfill. Making the interface generic is possible, but this is basically like writing a custom interface for every implementation, and then what's the point?